# Backbone View: Getting stuck with Zombie Events

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

My code gets the fileType and start new ImageView accordingly.

```
var frameIdRegion = new Marionette.Region({
                    el: '#viewerId'
                });


                // Create a new Backbone Marionette View with item model. Render View and Show it on Screen.
                if(fileType === 'Image'){
                    frameIdRegion.close(imageView);
                    frameIdRegion.reset();
                    var imageView = new ImageView({model: item});                   
                    frameIdRegion.show(imageView);              
                    $(".frameId img").show();
                    $(".frameId img").load(function(){
                        $("#fit_to_screen").trigger('click');
                    });
                    imageView.close();
                }
                else if(fileType === 'pdf'){
                    var objectView = new ObjectView({model: item});
                    frameIdRegion.reset();
                    frameIdRegion.show(objectView);
                    $("#pdf_viewer").show();
                    $('#pdf_viewer').trigger('focus');
                }
                else if(fileType === 'unsupported'){
                    var errorView = new ErrorView({model: item});
                    frameIdRegion.reset();
                    frameIdRegion.show(errorView);
                }
```

But my Old instance of ImageView is not getting cleared when i start a new ImageView. And my events are occuring many times. This is my ImageView code.

```
    var ImageView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
          template: template,
          className: 'frameId',
    onClose: function(){
             this.remove();
          this.unbind();
          this.model.unbind("change", this.modelChanged);
          }
});
```

Please help what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try using backbones `listenTo` function. It gets attached to whatever is calling it, so when your `ItemView` gets disposed then so will the event listener.

http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo

It also has a `stopListening` method if you really need it. When your view is removed, it should automatically stop listening to everything that was called by `listenTo`

http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove